# Java 8 LocalDateTime - How to keep .000 milliseconds in String conversion

Tags: java, datetime, format, datetime-format, java-time

I have a timestamp that I receive via a `String` in the following format:

> 2016-10-17T12:42:04.000

I am converting it to a `LocalDateTime` to add some days to it (then back to a `String`) via the following line:

```
String _120daysLater = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-10-17T12:42:04.000",
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")).minusDays(120).toString());
```

However, I noticed that the response it gives back drops the `.000` milliseconds.

I'm not sure the cleanest way to ensure that the exact pattern is preserved. For now I'm just adding a single millisecond, and there's probably a way to incorporate the old `SimpleDateFormat` into it, but I was hoping there's an even better way.

Comment: Just use the same DateTimeFormatter to format your LocalDateTime, instead of calling toString().

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[LocalDateTime::toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) omits parts if zero:

> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

Use [LocalDateTime::format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) instead of relying on `toString()`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime _120daysLater = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-10-17T12:42:04.000", formatter).minusDays(120);

// This just uses default formatting logic in toString. Don't rely on it if you want a specific format.
System.out.println(_120daysLater.toString());

// Use a format to use an explicitly defined output format
System.out.println(_120daysLater.format(formatter));
```