# DateTimeFormatter String to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I am trying to convert the value `2022-04-30 14:34:52.900426+00:00` an instance of `LocalDateTime`. I have written the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
```

I am getting the following error

> could not be parsed at index 26

What should my formatter string be?

Comment: `uuuu` is ever so slightly more likely than `yyyy`, but, mostly: What is that `'` doing there? There is no `'` in your input string. Get rid of that.

Comment: This could potentially be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043903/java-8-localdatetime-how-to-keep-000-milliseconds-in-string-conversion

Comment: 'Z' to parse "+00:00", i tried removing '' from Z but the given date is not getting parsed.  @rzwitserloot

Comment: Hint: use the `DateTimeFormat` to `format()` a `OffsetDateTime` to see what your format looks like (`'Z'` is just a literal `Z`)

Comment: @rzwitserloot Not saying it's needed here but the `'` is to mark literal text to match and is part of the format spec for `DateTimeFormatter` - it doesn't match a `'` in the input. See docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in the pattern letters table. They would be required if OP wanted to match a literal `Z` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the UTC Time offsets hasn't been written properly. It should look like this with a custom `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
//Custom DatTimeFormatter
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ");
formatter.parse("2022-04-30 14:34:52.900426+00:00");
```

You could either use the predefined `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` `DatTimeFormatter` **only** by replacing the space between date and time with a capital T, as the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) requires.

```
//Predefined DateTimeFormatter
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse("2022-04-30T14:34:52.900426+00:00");
```

Besides, to answer your question under @Taco Jan Osinga's reply:

No, it is not correct to use "+00:00" to just match the datetime you're trying to parse. That custom `DateTimeFormatter` you would build would only match datetime referring to your local TimeZone; thus it won't work with datetime from different areas.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime                          // Use `OffsetDateTime`, not `LocalDateTime`, to represent a date with time and offset. 
.parse( 
    "2022-04-30 14:34:52.900426+00:00"  // Almost in ISO 8601 format.
    .replace( " " , "T" )               // Replace SPACE with T to comply with ISO 8691.
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0XCDst).

## Wrong class, use `OffsetDateTime`, not `LocalDateTime`

`LocalDateTime` is exactly the wing class to use in this case. That represents a date with time-of-day. But your input indicates a date with time-of-day *and* an offset-from-UTC. The `+00:00` means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

So parse that input as a `OffsetDateTime` object instead.

Rather than define a formatting pattern, I suggest merely replacing the SPACE  in the middle with a `T` to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating text.

```
String input = "2022-04-30 14:34:52.900426+00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ; 
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+00:00"`?

Comment: It is working but is it right to use "+00:00" in case if date is from different time zones?

Comment: Then why use `Z`